# WordPress: rename all filenames with special characters and sync with database

Tags: wordpress, special-characters, filenames

It just turns out that the web host my client has doesn't allow any filenames with special characters (in this case the Swedish characters å,ä,ö). As they've already prepared the site content and uploaded dozens of images, I need to somehow batch rename these files, as well as sync it with the database. What would be the quickest option, considering I don't have SSH access to the server? What steps are needed to update WordPress for its posts' attachments?

Edit: Tried the plugin Media File Renamer but for some reason it didn't select a single file of those files that had special characters.

Comment: have you found a solution, that changed the file name and the DB entries?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for this @ [Wordpress Support page](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/upload-files-name-with-special-characters).

You can fix that by adding this script to your themes function.php file:

```
add_filter('sanitize_file_name', 'sa_sanitize_spanish_chars', 10);

function sa_sanitize_spanish_chars ($filename) {
    $spanish_chars = array( '/á/', '/é/', '/í/', '/ó/', '/ú/', '/ü/', '/ñ/', '/Á/', '/É/', '/Í/', '/Ó/', '/Ú/', '/Ü/', '/Ñ/', '/º/', '/ª/' );
    $sanitized_chars = array('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'u', 'n', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'U', 'N', 'o', 'a');
    $friendly_filename = preg_replace($spanish_chars, $sanitized_chars, $filename);
    return $friendly_filename;
}
```

This only adds support to spanish special characters, so if you want to sanitize swedish characters, you'll need to add them on both arrays.

Hope it helps!

Comment: just by adding that it did update the files already uploaded and updated as well the database?

Comment: I also need a solution for existing images

Comment: What this snippet does is sanitizing filenames upon upload time. It does not update existing files - so in order to get this working, you need to re-upload them.

Comment: this is not a solution for existing images